# Can "You are an officer and a gentleman" be used to praise a good deed done by a person completely unrelated to armed forces?

Tags: idioms, word-usage

Can "You are an officer and a gentleman" be used to praise a good deed done by a person completely unrelated to armed forces?

I would like to praise a friend of mine for an act of kindness. Is it appropriate to use this phrase for civilian people?

Comment: While it can be used that way, it is typically done on the spur of the moment. If, as it sounds from your question, a friend has done you a kindness and you are now contemplating how to thank him, I would not use the "officer and a gentleman" approach.  The nature of the kindness should determine the formality of your thanks.  If they've paid for your child's medical treatment without which he may have died then that requires a different level of thanks than if they picked up some papers you dropped while getting onto the elevator.

Answer (score 3):

I think OP is getting things confused with...

> ["You are a scholar and a gentleman"](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090328091256AAEs41h) (perhaps popularised for Americans by Catcher in the Rye)

Or the more natural order to my ear...

> ["You are a gentleman and a scholar"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22scholar%20and%20a%20gentleman%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22are%20a%20gentleman%20and%20a%20scholar%22&hl=en&tbo=1&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ei=LUKgUMmULa-W0QWwp4CoCA&ved=0CCUQpwUoAw&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=cd2c56685dba42a2&bpcl=38093640&biw=1223&bih=846) (that's a few C19 citations, showing it's been around a while).

It's probably safe to say it's usually said somewhat facetiously these days (the stereotypical usage is a drunk thanking someone for buying them another drink).

I think even if OP changes it from a *scholar* to an *officer*, outside the literal military context, most people would be put in mind of the above, so it probably wouldn't suit his intended contexts.

Eric Partidge's [Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=tvRp1whVFUsC&pg=PA28&dq=%22You%20are%20a%20gentleman%20and%20a%20scholar%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Y0egUNaQF8LP0QXWmYGwCw&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22You%20are%20a%20gentleman%20and%20a%20scholar%22&f=false) says that dating mostly from C16-C17 there were many variants on *...as I am a gentleman and scholar/officer/etc.*, used to mean *Believe me!*. But by later C20 they're all invariably used as ***"Jocular thanks"***.

Comment: I had a girlfriend who always said "You are gentleman and a schoolbus"

Comment: @StoneyB: I guess that one didn't work out then! (did you maybe used to tell her she had a face (or worse, an *arse*) [like the back end of a bus](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22like+the+back+end+of+a+bus%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)? :)

Comment: Certainly not. I was at least a gentleman.

Comment: A lieutenant reports for duty to new c.o. The colonel's batman announces lt.'s presence: Batman: 'An officer and a gentleman to see you, sir.' Col.: 'Very well, send them both in.'

Comment: I've mostly heard "You are a gentleman and a scholar", often used in a sort of (friendly) sarcastic/ironic sense.  I have occasionally heard (speaking to a civilian) "You are an officer and a gentleman", though, usually when discussing interactions with ladies.  (Once again, often sarcastic/ironic, but usually in a jocular sense.)

Comment: @Hot Licks: Suppose I *might* have heard *"You are an officer and a gentleman"* as mock-chivalry with no military context. But it *might* have seemed a bit out-of-place anyway. I'd probably use something like *"You are a true **ga'llant**!"* (stress on second syllable).